# String pattern search algorithm stack overflow

Tags: java, string, algorithm, pattern-matching, trie

I'm trying to modify [this code](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/KMPplus.java.html) to be a recursive version in order to have executing time efficiency. What the code does is to find all pattern's first indices in Text and add them to an ArrayList. My code is as below:

```
public boolean search(String text, int n, String pattern, int d) {
    if (n > text.length() || n < d) return true;
    while (d >= 0 && d < pattern.length() && n < text.length() && text.charAt(n) != pattern.charAt(d)) d = next[d];
    if (d == pattern.length()) {
    (***) if (ans == null || !ans.contains(n-d)) ans.add(n-d);                    
          n = n-d;
          d = -1;
    }
    if( n < text.length() && n >= d ) search(text, n+1, pattern, d+1);
    return false;
}
```

For-loop version of my code:

```
public void search(String text) {
int m = this.pattern.length();
int n = text.length();
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < m; i++) {
    while (j >= 0 && text.charAt(i) != this.pattern.charAt(j)) {
        j = next[j];
    }
    j++;
    if (j >= m) {
    if (ans == null || !ans.contains(i-m+1) ) ans.add(i-m+1);     
        j = 0;
        i = i - m + 1;
    }
}}
```

For worse case, it's exponential, that's why I'm unable to meet time limit.

Array `next[]` is the same as example code. My questions are:

1. When argument Text string is getting bigger, say more than 2200 characters, it always raised an `java.lang.StackOverflowError`; specifically in the line of three asterisks inside parenthesis. Even if only `ans.add(n-d)` left, still the same problem. Return value `boolean` is meanless, even if I changed function `return` type to be `void` and remove last line, it's still the same problem.
2. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What makes you think that a recursive version will be more efficient ? All it can be is slower. And as the message says, you experience stack overflow (because of heavy recursion). You'd better keep the original code.

Comment: Thanks Yves Daoust for your response. By using the last second condition, I don't have to go through all the way to the string end and stop while n < d. The original code's problem is that it always exceeds time limit.

Comment: One of the original code's problems is that it always exceeds time limit, and another is it can only get one index of pattern, what I need is to find all pattern's indices in Text.

Comment: Most of your code has no effect on the return value, which is always false once it gets past the first if.

Comment: @TaoWang: making the code recursive doesn't help. If you want to accelerate the algorithm, have a look at the classical solutions.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Currently the JVM (Hotspot) does not have tail call optimization. So each recursion will consume stack. So you get stackoverflow error. It's better to stick to iterative approach at the moment.